# Possible VS2012 compiler bug (maybe in Whole Program Optimization?)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compiler-optimization, compiler-bug

Could this be a compiler error?  My environment is:

- Win7 pro (64-bit)
- VS2012 (update 3)

I compile the tiny console program below.  Things work fine for x64 bit release/debug builds.  The x32 debug build also works just fine.  The x32 release build, however displays 'BUG!'.

If i disable 'Whole Program Optimization' that will fix the issue.

Any ideas?

-

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::string const buffer = "hello, world";
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    std::string::size_type previous_pos;


    while (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        previous_pos = ++pos;
        pos = buffer.find('w', pos);
    } 


    if (previous_pos == std::string::npos)
    {
        std::cout << "BUG!!"<< std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the loop goes around zero times, then previous_pos is uninitialized.

Comment: I couldn't tell you why, but the Disassembly window at that line shows `cmp eax, eax` followed by `jne`. Seems to suggest that yes, it is a bug.

Comment: What happens when you initialize previous_pos to zero? Perhaps the compiler is making some assumption based on the fact that it's uninitialized?

Comment: I just tried that myself and it makes no difference. Also, the program behavior seems to be correct if I change the platform toolset to Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: thanks for trying this, guys!  I've also tried the Nov CTP platform toolset - it shows the bug.

Comment: also, changing the pre-increment of pos to post-increment seems to make the bug go away.

Comment: Yeah, the 2013 Preview compiler does the same thing.

Comment: while (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        previous_pos = ++pos;
        pos = buffer.find('w', pos);
  std::cout << "Prev Pos: " << previous_pos << std::endl;
    } This is interesting. Adding a cout statement using previous_pos before the end of the loop also causes the bug to dissapear... Interesting question! I'm guessing this is something to do with compiler optimization?

Comment: Also, changing previous_post to = pos and pos = buffer.find('w', pos++) has some interesting results. In debug previous_pos will alternate between 0 and 7. In release 0 and 8.... Again, I'm using a cout in the loop here.

Comment: Hi David - I think that your suggestion of the line 'pos = buffer.find('w', pos++)' may be undefined as you are trying to modify the 'pos' variable twice in the same statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce this too.  When the bug manifests, the code is testing eax to deterimine whether to output "BUG", which is the same register it's using for 'pos'.

```
17:         previous_pos = ++pos;
```

013C12E5  inc         eax
...

```
21:     if (previous_pos == std::string::npos)
```

00301345  cmp         eax,eax
00301347  jne         main+0F6h (0301366h)

However if you make a change to try to get the optimzer to realise they are distinct then the test is different.  If I add ++previous_pos at the end of the loop body then it uses ecx for previous_pos and the bug goes away:

```
22:     if (previous_pos == std::string::npos)
```

00361349  cmp         ecx,eax
0036134B  jne         main+0FAh (036136Ah)

If I change the find to 'pos = buffer.find('w', previous_pos);' (searching from previous_pos instead of pos, which has the same value) then it uses ebx, and again the bug goes away:

```
21:     if (previous_pos == std::string::npos)
```

00191345  cmp         ebx,eax
00191347  jne         main+0F6h (0191366h)

So it seems in the original that the optimiser is erroneously deciding that it can use eax for both of those variables, despite the line 'pos = buffer.find('w', pos);' that can set pos to a different value than previous_pos.

Comment: So adding the cout statement causes the programme to realize it cannot use the same register? What about my last comment above about the register alternating between 0 and 7 in debug and 0 and 8 in release?

Comment: Thanks to all you guys for having a look at this issue.  Seems like everyone is in agreement that this is indeed a compiler bug, so I think i'll mark this as 'answered' now to close it off.